# Lambda as default constructor parameter in C++11 won't compile while using templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to learn some basics aspects of the C++0x, and while writing some code i have stumbled upon the following compilation error:

(I'm using 4.8.2 gcc)

> test.hpp:24:29: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘struct project::< lambda>’

This is the following snipped of the code I'm trying to deal with.

```
// case #1
template<class T = int> class Test {
 typedef std::function<void ()> Foo;
 ...
 public:
  Test(Foo const& foo = [] () {}){ // this is line 24
       }
     ...
    };
```

But the thing which makes me wonder is why the following code works (if the previous doesn't):

```
// case #2
template<class T = int> class Test {
 typedef std::function<void ()> Foo;
 ...
 public:
   Test(Foo const& foo = 0){
     foo = [] () {};
   }
 ...
};
```

Could someone explain why the case #1 doesn't compile and the #2 does?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code I don't see `Foo` anywhere

Comment: IIRC there's been some bug in g++ related to lambdas in default arguments.. Maybe try a more recent compiler?

Comment: I have compiled the gcc once more (sources: svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release) and still the error occurs. If it works for you, could you share your compiler version?

Comment: A minimal example compiles under [g++4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a43f309f14d34be)

Comment: My little bird brain forgot to also update g++ into alternatives. I'm terribly sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Why does it allow to assign to a const referenced `std::function`?